# Is a long "yes" written "はははははい" or "はーい"？

Tags: meaning, translation, expressions, help

How do I write a long はい？ I mean like when in anime, students all say "yeeeeees" to their sensei, is it written "はははははい" or "はーい"?

Comment: 「ははい」basically looks like a stutter

Comment: はははははい is like Yeyeyeyeyes.

Answer (score 2):

はーい is correct. You can add more dashes or use 〜 if you want, or you might spell it はぁい (or perhaps はあい), but ははい has an extra h-sound.